# Python click a tab on Excel ribbon

Tags: python

After I open my Excel file, I would like to use python to "click" on a tab, say data tab, and click on "Data Analysis" icon.

Can you please help me to do so?

Thank you, HHC

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pynput if you have to use python. Or you use vba to do this because this would be I think the easiest way for whatever your goal is. Just activate developer settings create new macro and edit the vba code which was generated for the macro and throw everything away you don't need because it always record more than you need.